# how to use preg_replace to extract negative-positive numbers from a string?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this:

```
SELECT NOW(),DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -11 day)
```

and I need to get the number which can be positive or negative.

I tried using:

```
preg_replace("/^-?[0-9]/", '', $str);
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try removing the `^` from the start of your regex; this tells the regex to only match numbers at the beginning of the string.

Comment: by saying extract are you trying to remove negative and positive numbers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to "extract" the number from the string, and not manipulate it then [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match) is what you should be using. If you want to remove numbers from a string then just remove the `^` from your regex which is restricting your regex to match the beginning of the string.

**Regex:**

```
/-?[0-9]+/  -- note that the + matches 1 or more numbers
```

**preg_match syntax:**

```
preg_match('/-?[0-9]+/', $str, $match);
```